# Label Numbering problem

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfig

Im trying to use subfigure command like that:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Problema com 7 nós e 9 veículos}
    \subfigure[Custo]{\label{fig17}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{part5-figuras/Solucoes/20 problemas ( 7 nÃ³s_9 veic ).png}}
    \subfigure[Histograma]{\label{fig18}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{part5-figuras/Solucoes/caminhoes 7-9.png}}
\end{figure}
```

and when I call the label it goes like:

[image]

[image]

Im in chapter 5 and it should be labeled 5.3(a) and 5.3(b) but it is numbering like 5.18 (This is the number of figures). I dont know if I must use some package or something. I have no clue about that

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, and please tell us whether you employ the `subfigure`, `subfig`, or `subcaption` package. And please explain why are you using `\eqref` instead of `\ref` to cross-reference (sub)figures.

Comment: Thank you. The documentclass is a maded one, called posMACd. I am using subfigure package (I saw it right now) and Im using \eqref for no strong reason. I just think it is better than \ref

Comment: ah! posMAC is my masters degree name course.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is obsolete and deprecated. Don't use it. Please use either the [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or the [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package.

Comment: I have to learn how to use subcaption then. I'll search on google right now.

Comment: It works!! I anwered below but I must wait 2 days to acept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Mico advice, I tryed use subcaption package and it works

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Problema com 7 nós e 9 veículos}
    \subcaptionbox{Custo\label{fig17}}{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{part5-figuras/Solucoes/20 problemas ( 7 nÃ³s_9 veic ).png}}
   \subcaptionbox{Histograma\label{fig18}}{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{part5-figuras/Solucoes/caminhoes 7-9.png}}
\end{figure}
```